# Laravel passport Expired Time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

i want to access token made with laravel passport has a refresh or an "extra time" eacth time user makes a request, but i really dont understand laravel documentation and each forum i've seen sends me there https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#refreshing-tokens i really dont understand witch parameters should i user, or where to get it.
So i decided to look for expiration time manually, Passport create 5 tables oauth accesToken, clients, personal_access_clients refresh_token and refresh_token, oauth_access_token has a column with expired_at field, so i thought if i change the time i'll get a longer token but i was wrong.
When i create token in boot method i set time

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
         'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        Passport::routes();

        Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(1));
        Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(1));
    }
```

this is working fine, but in login method

```
$tokenResult = $user->createToken('Token Acceso Personal');
$token = $tokenResult->token;
if ($request->remember_me) {
    $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
}
//this line it supose to set the expired time
$token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
//------------------
$userLogin->token = $tokenResult->accessToken;
$userLogin->save();
$token->save();
$profile = $people->where('user_id', $userLogin->id)->first();
$profile_name  = $profile2->where('id', $profile->profile_id)->first();
return response()->json([
                    'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
                    'token_type'   => 'Bearer',
                    'expires_at'   => Carbon::parse($tokenResult->token->expires_at)->toDateTimeString(),
                    'user_id'      => $userLogin->id,
                    'profile_id' => $profile->profile_id,
                    'profile_name' => $profile_name->name,
                    'companies'    => $companies
                ]);
```

when i set the time here it saves in DB but it doesnt work like expiration time, in other words, the expiration time in DB isn't working or it's not using it, so i'm curious if there is a place where should i look in order to find the expiration time setted in boot method or how could i set a longer time in token

Answer (score 0):

The property `$token->expires_at` is just a reference from the Database, what you can do is:

```
if ($request->remember_me) {
    Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addWeek());
}
```